# How can I prevent myself from accidentally using an NSNumber's pointer when I want its intValue?

Tags: java, objective-c, cocoa, nsnumber, autoboxing

One feature of Java that I really like is autoboxing, in which the compiler automatically converts between primitives and their wrapper classes.

I'm writing a Core Data application in Objective-C/Cocoa, and I'm finding it frustrating to deal with my integer attributes programmatically. Here's why:

```
//img is a managed object that I have fetched

NSString* filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.png", [[img valueForKey:@"imageID"] intValue]];
```

If I happen to forget the `intValue` message, which I sometimes do, then the int that gets passed to `stringWithFormat:` is actually the pointer value.

The problem is that this happens totally silently--no compiler error or warning. Sometimes I'll spend way too  long debugging when this silly, stupid thing is the problem.

Is there a way to change my programming style or my compiler settings to prevent me from getting caught in that trap?

**Edit**: I wasn't clear about the fact that the above example is just one of many places where I run into trouble. Here's another hypothetical example that doesn't have to do with strings:

Entity `CollegeClass` has two integer attributes: `courseNumber` and `enrollmentLimit`. Let's say I want to compare course numbers:

```
//classFoo is a NSManagedObjects I've fetched
if ([[classFoo valueForKey@"courseNumber"] intValue] < 400) {
    NSLog(@"undergraduate class");
}
```

Or similarly, suppose I want to compute the average enrollment limit for all the classes in the CS department.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> … suppose I want to compute the average enrollment limit for all the classes in the CS department.

This is easy to do with [NSArray's and NSSet's `@avg` operator](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Concepts/ArrayOperators.html). Of course, that will return an NSNumber, which puts you back in problem #2:

> Let's say I want to compare course numbers:
>
> ```
> //classFoo is a NSManagedObjects I've fetched
> if ([[classFoo valueForKey@"courseNumber"] intValue] < 400) {
>     NSLog(@"undergraduate class");
> }
> ```

I assume you mean that the problem you risk is omitting the `intValue` message, thereby comparing the NSNumber object's `id` to the `int`.

The compiler offers a warning for such comparisons. In Xcode, add `-Wextra` to your “Other C Flags” build setting. For more warning options, see [the full list of GCC warnings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use %@ to convert a NSNumber directly to a string instead of the %d.

It will actually take any NSObject based class and convert it to a string I believe.

Comment: It will send `descriptionWithLocale:` or `description` to the object and use that message's result. For CF objects (including CG, etc.), it calls `CFCopyDescription` on the object. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: Thanks for explaining the intricacies of it, I was unaware how it worked.

Comment: +1 This is a good idea for the string problem, but strings aren't my only issue. I edited the question to provide more examples.

Answer (score 3):

This is only applicable when dealing with Core Data, but if you use [MOGenerator](http://github.com/rentzsch/mogenerator) to generate classes for your Core Data objects (which I'd recommend doing anyway), you can then use `-[propertyName]Value` methods to directly access the correct value for properties which return `NSNumber`s:

```
// These two methods are identical when called on a class 
// which was generated with MOGenerator
[[object imageID] intValue];
[object imageIDValue];
```

Comment: I'd never heard of MOGenerator. That's a great idea, but I'm looking for something more fool-proof. The problem here is that I know I should be using intValue, but I sometimes forget.

That would only work if I could use [propertyName]Value for all of my attributes, not just numerical data, and then re-train myself to always use that.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the “Typecheck calls to `printf`/`scanf`” warning, if it isn't on already. This doesn't *currently* help with NS/CFString formatting, but I've filed a Radar enhancement request (x-radar://problem/7375186) for that. You're welcome to file your own, of course.